# Simple HTML Dom Scraping Google Result

Tags: php, html, xml, dom, web-scraping

I need to scrape the very little piece of text which Google returns to any enquiry as part of the "Knowledge Graph" result (the one generally on the right-hand side) which it gets from Wikipedia. This way I can then convert the plain-text to Voice Answer. Using Simple HTML Dom I have no problems scraping such info from Bing or Ask, but the very DIV (and SPAN) within which this result is nested on Google, I just can't get it. Simple function below:

```
$question = str_replace(' ','+',$_GET['question']);
$address = 'http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.$question;
$ret = scraping_Google($address);

function scraping_Google($url) {
    // create HTML DOM
    $html = file_get_html($url);

    // get title
    $ret = $html->find('div.kno-rdesc', 0)->plaintext;

    // clean up memory
    $html->clear();
    unset($html);

    return $ret;
}

echo $ret;
```

The very **div.kno-rdesc** is where the content is nested (this I easily retrieve using Code Inspector on Chrome). Yet, no success to parse this tiny piece of information. Anybody able to help out? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to scrape it.  Google has an API for that.  [Tap into the power of Google's Knowledge Graph with Freebase data](https://developers.google.com/freebase/)